# How to modify single (ranges of) characters within a custom environment?

Tags: formatting, environments, linguistics, italic

I am a historical linguist working with Hittite and Luwian texts, which have been transmitted to us in the cuneiform script. When citing words from these languages in articles etc., we usually do not include the cuneiform signs themselves but rather use transliterations in roman script, separating each character with a hyphen, e.g. *am-mu-uk* 'I, me'.

Within transliterations, all lowercase alphabetic characters (a-z) are normally italicised while uppercase letters and non-alphabetic characters (digits, brackets, hyphens, slashes) remain upright. Furthermore, all instances of *s* and *S* have a hacek, while *h* and *H* have a breve below them. Currently I am using separate commands (in XeLaTeX) to mark each of these diacritics/formats separately, adding haceks and breves using custom commands `\hacek{}` and `\invsubarch{}`, respectively. Thus, I write `\textsuperscript{DUG}\textit{\invsubarch{h}a}-\textit{ne}-\textit{e\hacek{s}}-\textit{n}[\textit{a}-\textit{a\hacek{s}}]` to create (as desired):

[image: Desired output]

I'd like to create a new environment `\hitt{}` in which all characters a-z are automatically italicised, and where every *s*/*S* and *h*/*H* is automatically replaced by `/hacek{s}` and `/invsubarch{h}`, respectively. Ideally I would be able to type the word in the preceding paragraph as `\hitt{\textsuperscript{DUG}ha-ne-es-n[a-as]}`.

Any help defining this new environment is greatly appreciated! Please let me know if additional information is required.

(My apologies if this question turns out to be a duplicate of another question. I have searched Google, StackExchange and StackOverflow, but have not been able to find a situation which - as far as I can judge - is comparable to mine.)

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!

Comment: Nice question! Probably easier to do in `lualatex`, but maybe some magic with font definition can do it... let see what the experts say. One small question: ¿are all uppercase letters always into `\textsuperscript` style, or it's just this example?

Comment: @Rmano Thank you! Unfortunately, not all uppercase letters are in `\textsuperscript{}`. Hittite makes abundant use of so-called Sumerograms and Akkadograms. These are signs which come from Sumerian and Akkadian texts, and retain the meaning they had in the language they were taken from. Per convention, we use upright uppercase to spell out Sumerograms (e.g. DINGIR = 'god'), and italic uppercase to write Akkadograms (e.g. *A-BU* = 'father').

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do regular expression search and replace. In particular, `s` and `S` are changed into the character followed by U+030C (COMBINING CARON), which XeTeX will normalize to `š` and `Š` respectively; similarly for `h` and `H`, with U+032E (COMBINING BREVE BELOW) that are normalized to `ḫ` and `Ḫ`.

I took the occasion for suggesting `|...|` instead of `\textsuperscript{...}`, adding a substitution for this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xparse}

\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\hitt}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_xander_hitt_tl { #1 }
  % change every run of lowercase letters into italic
  \regex_replace_all:nnN
   { [a-z]+ }
   { \c{textit}\cB\{\0\cE\} }
   \l_xander_hitt_tl
  % change every h/H into h/H U+032E
  \regex_replace_all:nnN
   { [hH] }
   { \0 \x{032e} }
   \l_xander_hitt_tl
  % change every s/S into s/S U+032E
  \regex_replace_all:nnN
   { [sS] }
   { \0 \x{030c} }
   \l_xander_hitt_tl
  % change |...| into \textsuperscript{...}
  \regex_replace_all:nnN
   { \|([^|]+)\| }
   { \c{textsuperscript}\cB\{\1\cE\} }
   \l_xander_hitt_tl
  % print the result
  \tl_use:N \l_xander_hitt_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\hitt{|DUG|ha-ne-es-n[a-as]}

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Notes

1. `[a-z]+` stands for a run of one or more lowercase letters
2. `\c{textit}` means “the control sequence `\textit`”
3. `\cB\{` and `\cE\}` stand for the group-making TeX braces
4. `\x{<hex digits>}` stands for the character with the corresponding code
5. `\0` in replacement strings denotes the match; `\1` is the first capturing group
6. `\|([^|]*)\|` searches for `|` (it must be escaped in search strings) followed by any run of tokens different from `|` up to finding the matching `|`

Comment: Thank you for this solution and for the detailed notes! It works like a charm :)

Answer (score 2):

Possibilities open up.

Not an answer, but the potential of an extension: the rubification of Hittite text (and also Old Persian, Ugaritic and so on).

Using a mapping file with a "plain" text input methodology, so that egreg's environment takes care of 's' and 'h' and, with an addition, doubled vowels become single-letter acute, and then compiling with xelatex:

[image: hinyin, or ruby hittite text]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{stackengine}


\setmainfont{Linux Libertine} 
\newfontface\hitt{Noto Sans Cuneiform}


\newfontface\fmhitt[Mapping=latin-to-hittite2,Colour=blue]{Noto Sans Cuneiform}



\DeclareTextFontCommand{\texthitt}{\Large\fmhitt}



\newenvironment{thitt}
  {\fmhitt\Large\ignorespaces}
  {\ignorespacesafterend}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\ehitt}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_xander_hitt_tl { #1 }
  % change every run of lowercase letters into italic
  \regex_replace_all:nnN
   { [a-z]+ }
   { \c{textit}\cB\{\0\cE\} }
   \l_xander_hitt_tl
  % change every h/H into h/H U+032E
  \regex_replace_all:nnN
   { [hH] }
   { \0 \x{032e} }
   \l_xander_hitt_tl
  % change every s/S into s/S U+032E
  \regex_replace_all:nnN
   { [sS] }
   { \0 \x{030c} }
   \l_xander_hitt_tl
  % change every double vowel aa/ into a/ U+0301
  \regex_replace_all:nnN
   { ([a,e,i,u]){2,2} }
   { \1 \x{0301} }
   \l_xander_hitt_tl
  % change |...| into \textsuperscript{...}
  \regex_replace_all:nnN
   { \|([^|]+)\| }
   { \c{textsuperscript}\cB\{\c{textsc}\cB\{\1\cE\}\cE\} 
    }
   \l_xander_hitt_tl
  % print the result
  \tl_use:N \l_xander_hitt_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

  
  
\newcommand\hstackon[2]{\stackon{\begin{thitt}#1\end{thitt}}{\ehitt{#2}}}  

\begin{document}
\section{Hittite}
\hstackon{|dug|}{|dug|}
\hstackon{ha}{ha}
\hstackon{ne}{ne}
\hstackon{es}{es}
\hstackon{na}{na}
\hstackon{as}{as}



Random text from the UChicago \textit{Hittite Dictionary}, volume \textbf{P}, p 144, sv \ehitt{parh-} (chase): "and may the oath deities pursue you continuously"


\begin{center}
\hstackon{niis}{|niis|}
\hstackon{dingir}{|dingir|}
\hstackon{mes}{|mes|}
\hstackon{paar}{paar}
\hstackon{he}{he}
\hstackon{es}{es}
\hstackon{kaan}{kaan}
\hstackon{du}{du}
\end{center}


\begin{center}
\hstackon{|niis.dingir.mes|paar-he-es-kaan-du}{|niis.dingir.mes|paar-he-es-kaan-du}
\end{center}

Mapping file (based on Wikipedia article) is incomplete, having the syllables (V, VC, VC, CVC) and a few determiners. Glyph for \textsc{\ehitt{niis}} needs to be tracked down; keyed in as \texttt{niis}, it is obviously incorrect as it is being parsed as the two syllables \texttt{ni} + \texttt{is}:  \hstackon{ni}{ni}\hstackon{is}{is} by the font map.

Otherwise, some general formatting required (e.g., struts or similar to line up the ruby text).



\end{document}
```

Map file, to compile with teckit_compile.exe:

```
; TECkit mapping for TeX input conventions <-> Unicode characters

LHSName "latin-to-hittite"
RHSName "UNICODE"

pass(Unicode)

; ligatures from Knuth's original CMR fonts
U+002D U+002D           <>  U+2013  ; -- -> en dash
U+002D U+002D U+002D    <>  U+2014  ; --- -> em dash

U+0027          <>  U+2019  ; ' -> right single quote
U+0027 U+0027   <>  U+201D  ; '' -> right double quote
U+0022           >  U+201D  ; " -> right double quote

U+0060          <>  U+2018  ; ` -> left single quote
U+0060 U+0060   <>  U+201C  ; `` -> left double quote

U+0021 U+0060   <>  U+00A1  ; !` -> inverted exclam
U+003F U+0060   <>  U+00BF  ; ?` -> inverted question

; additions supported in T1 encoding
U+002C U+002C   <>  U+201E  ; ,, -> DOUBLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK
U+003C U+003C   <>  U+00AB  ; << -> LEFT POINTING GUILLEMET
U+003E U+003E   <>  U+00BB  ; >> -> RIGHT POINTING GUILLEMET


;U+0020    >  U+0020 ;  space maps to space
U+002D    >  U+200D ;  hyphen as Zero Width Joiner
U+002E    >  U+200D ;  dot as Zero Width Joiner
U+007C    >  U+200C ;  pipe as Zero Width Non-Joiner


U+0061    <>  U+12000 ;  a 
U+0065    <>  U+1208A ;  e 
U+0069    <>  U+1213F ;  i 
U+0075    <>  U+1230B ;  u 
U+0075 U+0075   <>  U+12311 ;  uu 
U+0062 U+0061   <>  U+12040 ;  ba 
U+0070 U+0061   <>  U+1227A ;  pa 
U+0064 U+0061   <>  U+12055 ;  da 
U+0074 U+0061   <>  U+122EB ;  ta 
U+0067 U+0061   <>  U+120B5 ;  ga 
U+006B U+0061   <>  U+12157 ;  ka 
U+0068 U+0061   <>  U+12129 ;  ha 
U+006C U+0061   <>  U+121B7 ;  la 
U+006D U+0061   <>  U+12220 ;  ma 
U+006E U+0061   <>  U+1223E ;  na 
U+0072 U+0061   <>  U+1228F ;  ra 
U+0073 U+0061   <>  U+122AD ;  sa 
U+0077 U+0061   <>  U+1227F ;  wa 
U+0079 U+0061   <>  U+12140 ;  ya 
U+007A U+0061   <>  U+1235D ;  za 
U+0062 U+0065   <>  U+12041 ;  be 
U+0070 U+0065 U+0065  <>  U+12049 ;  pee 
U+0070 U+0069 U+0069  <>  U+12049 ;  pii 
U+0062 U+0069   <>  U+12049 ;  bi 
U+0064 U+0065   <>  U+12072 ;  de 
U+0064 U+0069   <>  U+12072 ;  di 
U+0074 U+0065   <>  U+122FC ;  te 
U+0074 U+0069   <>  U+122FE ;  ti 
U+0067 U+0065   <>  U+12100 ;  ge 
U+0067 U+0069   <>  U+12100 ;  gi 
U+006B U+0065   <>  U+121A0 ;  ke 
U+006B U+0069   <>  U+121A0 ;  ki 
U+0068 U+0065   <>  U+1212D ;  he 
U+0068 U+0065 U+0065  <>  U+120F6 ;  hee 
U+0068 U+0069   <>  U+1212D ;  hi 
U+006C U+0065   <>  U+121F7 ;  le 
U+006C U+0069   <>  U+121F7 ;  li 
U+006D U+0065   <>  U+12228 ;  me 
U+006D U+0065 U+0065  <>  U+1222A ;  mee 
U+006D U+0069   <>  U+1222A ;  mi 
U+006E U+0065   <>  U+12248 ;  ne 
U+006E U+0065 U+0065  <>  U+1224C ;  nee 
U+006E U+0069   <>  U+1224C ;  ni 
U+0072 U+0065   <>  U+12291 ;  re 
U+0072 U+0069   <>  U+12291 ;  ri 
U+0073 U+0065   <>  U+122BA ;  se 
U+0073 U+0069   <>  U+12146 ;  si 
U+0077 U+0069   <>  U+120FE ;  wi 
U+007A U+0065   <>  U+12363 ;  ze 
U+007A U+0065 U+0065  <>  U+12362 ;  zee 
U+007A U+0069   <>  U+12363 ;  zi 
U+0062 U+0075   <>  U+1204D ;  bu 
U+0070 U+0075   <>  U+1204D ;  pu 
U+0064 U+0075   <>  U+1207A ;  du 
U+0074 U+0075   <>  U+12305 ;  tu 
U+0067 U+0075   <>  U+12116 ;  gu 
U+006B U+0075   <>  U+121AA ;  ku 
U+0068 U+0075   <>  U+12137 ;  hu 
U+006C U+0075   <>  U+121FB ;  lu 
U+006D U+0075   <>  U+1222C ;  mu 
U+006E U+0075   <>  U+12261 ;  nu 
U+0072 U+0075   <>  U+12292 ;  ru 
U+0073 U+0075   <>  U+122D7 ;  su 
U+0073 U+0075 U+0075  <>  U+122D9 ;  suu 
U+007A U+0075   <>  U+1236A ;  zu 
U+0061 U+0062   <>  U+1200A ;  ab 
U+0061 U+0070   <>  U+1200A ;  ap 
U+0061 U+0064   <>  U+1201C ;  ad 
U+0061 U+0074   <>  U+1201C ;  at 
U+0061 U+0067   <>  U+1201D ;  ag 
U+0061 U+006B   <>  U+1201D ;  ak 
U+0061 U+0068   <>  U+12134 ;  ah 
U+0065 U+0068   <>  U+12134 ;  eh 
U+0069 U+0068   <>  U+12134 ;  ih 
U+0075 U+0068   <>  U+12134 ;  uh 
U+0061 U+006C   <>  U+12020 ;  al 
U+0061 U+006D   <>  U+12120 ;  am 
U+0061 U+006E   <>  U+1202D ;  an 
U+0061 U+0072   <>  U+12148 ;  ar 
U+0061 U+0073   <>  U+12038 ;  as 
U+0061 U+007A   <>  U+1228D ;  az 
U+0065 U+0062   <>  U+12141 ;  eb 
U+0065 U+0070   <>  U+12141 ;  ep 
U+0069 U+0062   <>  U+12141 ;  ib 
U+0069 U+0070   <>  U+12141 ;  ip 
U+0065 U+0064   <>  U+12009 ;  ed 
U+0065 U+0074   <>  U+12009 ;  et 
U+0069 U+0064   <>  U+12009 ;  id 
U+0069 U+0074   <>  U+12009 ;  it 
U+0065 U+0067   <>  U+12145 ;  eg 
U+0065 U+006B   <>  U+12145 ;  ek 
U+0069 U+0067   <>  U+12145 ;  ig 
U+0069 U+006B   <>  U+12145 ;  ik 
U+0065 U+006C   <>  U+12096 ;  el 
U+0069 U+006C   <>  U+1214B ;  il 
U+0065 U+006D   <>  U+1214E ;  em 
U+0069 U+006D   <>  U+1214E ;  im 
U+0065 U+006E   <>  U+12097 ;  en 
U+0069 U+006E   <>  U+12154 ;  in 
U+0065 U+0072   <>  U+12155 ;  er 
U+0069 U+0072   <>  U+12155 ;  ir 
U+0065 U+0073   <>  U+1230D ;  es 
U+0065 U+0073 U+0073  <>  U+12401 ;  ess 
U+0069 U+0073   <>  U+12156 ;  is 
U+0065 U+007A   <>  U+12111 ;  ez 
U+0069 U+007A   <>  U+12111 ;  iz 
U+0075 U+0062   <>  U+12312 ;  ub 
U+0075 U+0070   <>  U+12312 ;  up 
U+0075 U+0064   <>  U+12313 ;  ud 
U+0075 U+0074   <>  U+12313 ;  ut 
U+0075 U+0067   <>  U+1228C ;  ug 
U+0075 U+006B   <>  U+1228C ;  uk 
U+0075 U+006C   <>  U+1230C ;  ul 
U+0075 U+006D   <>  U+1231D ;  um 
U+0075 U+006E   <>  U+12326 ;  un 
U+0075 U+0072   <>  U+12328 ;  ur 
U+0075 U+0075 U+0072  <>  U+1232B ;  uur 
U+0075 U+0073   <>  U+12351 ;  us 
U+0075 U+007A   <>  U+122BB ;  uz 


U+0068 U+0061 U+006C  <>  U+1212C    ;  hal 
U+0068 U+0061 U+0062  <>  U+121B8    ;  hab 
U+0068 U+0061 U+0070  <>  U+121B8    ;  hap 
U+0068 U+0061 U+0073  <>  U+122FB    ;  has 
U+0068 U+0061 U+0064  <>  U+1227A    ;  had 
U+0068 U+0061 U+0074  <>  U+1227A    ;  hat 
U+0068 U+0075 U+006C  <>  U+003F    ;  hul ?
U+0068 U+0075 U+0062  <>  U+1213D    ;  hub 
U+0068 U+0075 U+0070  <>  U+1213D    ;  hup 
U+0068 U+0061 U+0072  <>  U+1212F    ;  har 
U+0068 U+0075 U+0072  <>  U+1212F    ;  hur 
U+0067 U+0061 U+006C  <>  U+120F2    ;  gal 
U+006B U+0061 U+006C  <>  U+12197    ;  kal 
U+0067 U+0061 U+006C U+0067      <>  U+12197    ;  galg 
U+006B U+0061 U+006D  <>  U+12130    ;  kam 
U+0067 U+0061 U+0061 U+006D      <>  U+12130    ;  gaam 
U+006B U+0061 U+0061 U+006E      <>  U+120F7    ;  kaan 
U+0067 U+0061 U+0061  <>  U+120F7    ;  gaan 
U+006B U+0061 U+0062  <>  U+1218F    ;  kab 
U+006B U+0061 U+0070  <>  U+1218F    ;  kap 
U+0067 U+0061 U+0061 U+0062      <>  U+1218F    ;  gaab 
U+0067 U+0061 U+0061 U+0070      <>  U+1218F    ;  gaap 
U+006B U+0061 U+0072  <>  U+003F    ;  kar ?
U+006B U+0061 U+0061 U+0072      <>  U+120FC    ;  kaar 
U+0067 U+0061 U+0061 U+0072      <>  U+120FC    ;  gaar 
U+006B U+0061 U+0064  <>  U+120F0    ;  kad 
U+006B U+0061 U+0074  <>  U+120F0    ;  kat 
U+0067 U+0061 U+0064  <>  U+120F0    ;  gad 
U+0067 U+0061 U+0074  <>  U+120F0    ;  gat 
U+0067 U+0061 U+007A  <>  U+12124    ;  gaz 
U+006B U+0069 U+0062  <>  U+003F    ;  kib ?
U+006B U+0069 U+0070  <>  U+003F    ;  kip ?
U+006B U+0069 U+0072  <>  U+1212B    ;  kir 
U+0067 U+0069 U+0072  <>  U+1212B    ;  gir 
U+006B U+0069 U+0073  <>  U+121A7    ;  kis 
U+006B U+0069 U+0064  <>  U+120F0    ;  kid 
U+006B U+0069 U+0074  <>  U+120F0    ;  kit 
U+006B U+0061 U+006C U+006C      <>  U+12197    ;  kall 
U+006B U+0075 U+006C  <>  U+121B0    ;  kul 
U+006B U+0075 U+0075 U+006C      <>  U+12122    ;  kuul 
U+0067 U+0075 U+006C  <>  U+12122    ;  gul 
U+006B U+0075 U+006D  <>  U+12123    ;  kum 
U+0067 U+0075 U+006D  <>  U+12123    ;  gum 
U+006B U+0075 U+0072  <>  U+121B3    ;  kur 
U+006B U+0075 U+0075 U+0072      <>  U+12125    ;  kuur 
U+0067 U+0075 U+0072  <>  U+12125    ;  gur 
U+006C U+0061 U+006C  <>  U+121F2    ;  lal 
U+006C U+0061 U+006D  <>  U+121F4    ;  lam 
U+006C U+0069 U+0067  <>  U+12328    ;  lig 
U+006C U+0069 U+006B  <>  U+12328    ;  lik 
U+006C U+0069 U+0073  <>  U+121FA    ;  lis 
U+006C U+0075 U+0068  <>  U+1221B    ;  luh 
U+006C U+0075 U+006D  <>  U+1221D    ;  lum 
U+006D U+0061 U+0068  <>  U+12224    ;  mah 
U+006D U+0061 U+006E  <>  U+003F    ;  man ?
U+006D U+0061 U+0072  <>  U+12225    ;  mar 
U+006D U+0061 U+0073  <>  U+12226    ;  mas 
;U+006D U+0065 U+0073  <>  U+003F    ;  mes ?
U+006D U+0069 U+006C  <>  U+12156    ;  mil 
U+006D U+0065 U+006C  <>  U+12156    ;  mel 
U+006D U+0069 U+0073  <>  U+12229    ;  mis 
U+006D U+0075 U+0072  <>  U+1212F    ;  mur 
U+006D U+0075 U+0074  <>  U+003F    ;  mut ?
U+006E U+0061 U+006D  <>  U+12246    ;  nam 
U+006E U+0061 U+0062  <>  U+1202E    ;  nab 
U+006E U+0061 U+0070  <>  U+1202E    ;  nap 
U+006E U+0069 U+0072  <>  U+1226A    ;  nir 
U+006E U+0069 U+0073  <>  U+003F    ;  nis ?
U+0062 U+0061 U+006C  <>  U+12044    ;  bal 
U+0070 U+0061 U+006C  <>  U+12044    ;  pal 
U+0062 U+0061 U+0072  <>  U+12226    ;  bar 
U+0070 U+0061 U+0061 U+0072      <>  U+12226    ;  paar 
U+0070 U+0061 U+0073  <>  U+003F    ;  pas ?
U+0070 U+0061 U+0061 U+0064      <>  U+12041    ;  paad 
U+0070 U+0061 U+0061 U+0074      <>  U+12041    ;  paat 
U+0070 U+0069 U+0069 U+0064      <>  U+12041    ;  piid 
U+0070 U+0069 U+0069 U+0074      <>  U+12041    ;  piit 
U+0062 U+0069 U+0069 U+006C      <>  U+1224B    ;  biil 
U+0070 U+0069 U+0069 U+006C      <>  U+1224B    ;  piil 
U+0070 U+0069 U+0072  <>  U+003F    ;  pir ?
U+0062 U+0069 U+0073  <>  U+1212B    ;  bis 
U+0070 U+0069 U+0073  <>  U+1212B    ;  pis 
U+0070 U+0075 U+0075 U+0073      <>  U+1212B    ;  puus 
U+0062 U+0075 U+0072  <>  U+003F    ;  bur ?
U+0070 U+0075 U+0072  <>  U+003F    ;  pur ?
U+0072 U+0061 U+0064       <>  U+122E5    ;  rad 
U+0072 U+0061 U+0074       <>  U+122E5    ;  rat 
U+0072 U+0069 U+0073  <>  U+12295    ;  ris 
U+0073 U+0061 U+0068  <>  U+122DA    ;  sah 
U+0073 U+0061 U+0067  <>  U+12295    ;  sag 
U+0073 U+0061 U+006B  <>  U+12295    ;  sak 
U+0073 U+0061 U+006C  <>  U+122A9    ;  sal 
U+0073 U+0061 U+006D  <>  U+12311    ;  sam 
U+0073 U+0061 U+0062  <>  U+003F    ;  sab ?
U+0073 U+0061 U+0070  <>  U+003F    ;  sap ?
U+0073 U+0061 U+0072  <>  U+122AC    ;  sar 
U+0073 U+0069 U+0069 U+0070      <>  U+003F    ;  siip ?
U+0073 U+0069 U+0072  <>  U+122D3    ;  sir 
U+0073 U+0075 U+006D  <>  U+122F3    ;  sum 
U+0073 U+0075 U+0072       <>  U+122E9    ;  sur 
U+0064 U+0061 U+0068  <>  U+1222D    ;  dah 
U+0074 U+0061 U+0068  <>  U+1222D    ;  tah 
U+0074 U+0075 U+0075 U+0068      <>  U+1222D    ;  tuuh 
U+0074 U+0061 U+0061 U+0067      <>  U+12056    ;  taag 
U+0074 U+0061 U+0061 U+006B      <>  U+12056    ;  taak 
U+0064 U+0061 U+0067  <>  U+12056    ;  dag 
U+0064 U+0061 U+006B  <>  U+12056    ;  dak 
U+0064 U+0061 U+006C  <>  U+12291    ;  dal 
U+0074 U+0061 U+006C  <>  U+12291    ;  tal 
U+0064 U+0061 U+006D  <>  U+1206E    ;  dam 
U+0074 U+0061 U+0061 U+006D      <>  U+1206E    ;  taam 
U+0064 U+0061 U+006E  <>  U+12197    ;  dan 
U+0074 U+0061 U+006E  <>  U+12197    ;  tan 
U+0074 U+0061 U+0062  <>  U+122F0    ;  tab 
U+0074 U+0061 U+0070  <>  U+122F0    ;  tap 
U+0064 U+0061 U+0061 U+0062      <>  U+122F0    ;  daab 
U+0064 U+0061 U+0061 U+0070      <>  U+122F0    ;  daap 
U+0074 U+0061 U+0072  <>  U+122FB    ;  tar 
U+0064 U+0061 U+0061 U+0073      <>  U+12079    ;  daas 
U+0074 U+0061 U+0061 U+0073      <>  U+12079    ;  taas 
U+0064 U+0069 U+0073  <>  U+12079    ;  dis 
U+0074 U+0069 U+0073  <>  U+12079    ;  tis 
U+0074 U+0061 U+0061  <>  U+1203E    ;  taas 
U+0074 U+0069 U+006E  <>  U+12077    ;  tin 
U+0074 U+0065 U+0065 U+006E      <>  U+12077    ;  teen 
U+0064 U+0069 U+006D  <>  U+12074    ;  dim 
U+0074 U+0069 U+006D  <>  U+12074    ;  tim 
U+0064 U+0069 U+0072  <>  U+003F    ;  dir ?
U+0074 U+0065 U+0072  <>  U+12301    ;  ter 
U+0074 U+0069 U+0072  <>  U+12301    ;  tir 
U+0074 U+0069 U+0069 U+0073      <>  U+003F    ;  tiis ?
U+0074 U+0075 U+0075 U+006C      <>  U+121E5    ;  tuul 
U+0064 U+0075 U+006D  <>  U+12308    ;  dum 
U+0074 U+0075 U+006D  <>  U+12308    ;  tum 
U+0064 U+0075 U+0062  <>  U+1207E    ;  dub 
U+0064 U+0075 U+0070  <>  U+1207E    ;  dup 
U+0074 U+0075 U+0062  <>  U+1207E    ;  tub 
U+0074 U+0075 U+0070  <>  U+1207E    ;  tup 
U+0064 U+0075 U+0072  <>  U+12119    ;  dur 
U+0074 U+0075 U+0075 U+0072      <>  U+12119    ;  tuur 
U+007A U+0075 U+006C  <>  U+12084    ;  zul 
U+007A U+0075 U+006D  <>  U+1236E    ;  zum 
U+0064 U+0069 U+0073  <>  U+12079    ;  dis 
U+0064 U+0069 U+0064 U+006C U+0069     <>  U+12038    ;  didli 
U+0064 U+0069 U+0064 U+006C U+0069 U+0068 U+0069 U+0061  <>  U+12038 U+1212D U+12000  ;  didlihia 
U+0064 U+0069 U+006E U+0067 U+0069 U+0072    <>  U+1202D    ;  dingir 
U+0064 U+0075 U+0067  <>  U+12081    ;  dug 
U+0065 U+0065   <>  U+1208D    ;  ee 
U+0067 U+0061 U+0064  <>  U+120F0    ;  gad 
U+0067 U+0069   <>  U+12100    ;  gi 
U+0067 U+0069 U+0073  <>  U+12111    ;  gis 
U+0067 U+0075 U+0064  <>  U+1211E    ;  gud 
U+0068 U+0069 U+0061       <>  U+1212D U+12000   ;  hia 
U+0068 U+0075 U+0072 U+0073 U+0061 U+0067    <>  U+1212F U+12295   ;  hursag 
U+0069 U+0069 U+0064  <>  U+003F    ;  iid ?
U+0069 U+006D   <>  U+1214E    ;  im 
U+0069 U+0074 U+0075  <>  U+1231A    ;  itu 
U+006B U+0061 U+006D  <>  U+12130    ;  kam 
U+006B U+0069   <>  U+121A0    ;  ki 
U+006B U+0075   <>  U+12129    ;  ku 
U+006B U+0075 U+0072  <>  U+121B3    ;  kur 
U+006B U+0075 U+0073  <>  U+12200    ;  kus 
U+006C U+0075 U+0075  <>  U+121FD    ;  luu 
U+006D U+0065 U+0073  <>  U+12228 U+1230D   ;  mes 
U+006D U+0065 U+0073 U+0068 U+0069 U+0061    <>  U+12228 U+1230D U+1212D U+12000 ;  meshia 
U+006D U+0075 U+006C  <>  U+1202F    ;  mul 
U+006D U+0075 U+006E U+0075 U+0073     <>  U+122A9    ;  munus 
U+006D U+0075 U+0073  <>  U+12232    ;  mus 
U+006D U+0075 U+0073 U+0065 U+006E     <>  U+12137    ;  musen 
U+006E U+0061   <>  U+003F    ;  na ?
U+006E U+0069 U+006E U+0064 U+0061     <>  U+120FB    ;  ninda 
U+0070 U+0075 U+0075  <>  U+003F    ;  puu ?
U+0073 U+0061 U+0072  <>  U+122AC    ;  sar 
U+0073 U+0069   <>  U+122DB    ;  si 
U+0073 U+0069 U+0069  <>  U+0122    ;  siig 
U+0074 U+0075   <>  U+12130    ;  tu 
U+0074 U+0075 U+0075  <>  U+12306    ;  tuug 
U+0075 U+0075   <>  U+12311    ;  uu 
U+0075 U+0072 U+0075  <>  U+12337    ;  uru 
U+0075 U+0072 U+0075 U+0064 U+0075     <>  U+12350    ;  urudu 
U+0075 U+007A U+0075  <>  U+1235C    ;  uzu
```

---

*Addendum*

The regular expression method is more versatile, not being restricted to xelatex like Teckit maps are.

This is some Ugaritic script rubification:

[image: Ruby Ugaritic]

Full (experimental) MWE for Ugaritic, which is intended for producing Ugaritic text using an ASCII transliteration input method, is too big for here and is at
[Github](https://github.com/texcicada/trannsliteration): [.tex file](https://github.com/texcicada/trannsliteration/blob/main/ugtrans.tex) and [PDF](https://github.com/texcicada/trannsliteration/blob/main/ugtrans.pdf).